# Macbook Pro 2016 (13,1) won't show bootable Ubuntu live USB drive on boot after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: usb, startup

I've been using a dual boot Macbook Pro 2016 (13,1) running MacOS and Ubuntu for the last 4 years. Today, after updating to Big Sur, my bootable live USB drive won't show when holding down Option key on boot. I wanted to boot a live Ubuntu USB drive to change something on my Linux partition, but the USB boot option won't show up.

I've checked that the drive shows and boots in another macbook air I have at home. Also, I use rEFInd in my Macbook Pro, but the USB also won't show there. SIP is disabled. Any ideas? Does Big Sur changes the booting process?